# Getting return value from a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

consider the the two functions :

```
int add1(int x,int y)
{
return x+y;
}


void add2(int x,int y,int *sum)
{
*sum=x+y;
}
```

I generally use functions of the form add1 but I found some codes using functions of the form add2.
Even if the size return value is large(like an array or struct) we can just return its ponter
I wonder if there any reason for using the second form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the reason of returning success state.

There are a lot of functions like:

```
bool f(int arg1, int arg2, int *ret)
{
}
```

Where `bool` (or `enum`) return the success of the function. Instead of checking `if ret is null...` (And if you had more than 1 variable).

Comment: well you pass more arguments to the function so you use the stack more but it's meaningless... especially when transferring pointers..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return two values from your function, then C is helpless unless you use pointers just like your function add2.

```
void add2()
{

 /* Some Code */

 *ptr1=Something;
 *ptr2=Something;
}
```

Comment: +1, also useful if a parameter is used for both input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Form 2 is very common for "multiple returns" in C. A canonical example is returning the address to a buffer and the length of the buffer:

```
/* Returns a buffer based on param. Returns -1 on failure, or 0 on success.
Buffer is returned in buf and buflen. */
int get_buffer(void *param, char **buf, int *buflen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions of the form 2 are not faster than functions of the form 1 when you're using things as small as `int`. In fact, in this case, the second one is slower because you have to **dereference** the passed pointer. It's only useful in this case if your aim was to pass in an array of values)

Always use functions of the form 1 unless you want to pass in a **very large piece of data** to the function. In that case, the form 2 would be faster.

The reason we use the second form is because for large objects, we want to avoid copying them. Instead of **copying** them, we could just pass their **memory addresses** to the function. This is where the pointer comes in. So instead of giving the function **all the data**, you would just tell it **where this data**. (I hope this analogy is good enough)

Answer (score 0):

It is largely a matter of preference and local conventions.  The second form might be used alongside a bunch of other similar functions where the third parameter in each of them is always passed as a pointer to a return value.

Personally, I like the first form for almost all purposes:  it does not require a pointer to be passed, and it allows some type flexibility in handling the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value by writing to memory passed via a pointer is reasonable, when the returned object is large, or when the return value of the function is used for other purposes (e.g. signaling error conditions). In the code you have shown, neither of these two is the case, so I'd go for the first implementation.

When you return a pointer from a function, you have to make sure that the pointed to memory is valid after the function call. This means, the pointer must point to the heap, making an allocation on the heap necessary. This puts a burdon on the caller; he has to deallocate memory that he did not explicitly allocate.